# How to not allow whitespace in one particular rule - grammar skips whitespace correctly otherwise

Tags: antlr4

Our grammar allows a user to specify a tag either by an ID (friendly name) or an INDEX via an editor. The grammar snippet looks like this:

```
tagindex
 : DOLLARDOLLAR 'TAGINDEX' ASSIGN tagid=INT DOLLARDOLLAR
 ;

// A tag is either an ID or an INDEX
tag
: ID                            
| tagindex                          
;
```

We use the 'tagindex' rule since that allows us to easily access the tagid (or yeah INT) token in the Listener (EnterTagindex) and Visitor (VisitTagindex), but that also means that the user can enter spaces in between each token since our grammar skips white space.

What we need is for 'tagindex' to not accept any spaces so that the user is forced to enter e.g:

```
$$TAGINDEX=123$$
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `tagindex` isn't recursive and doesn't use any non-terminal rules, you can make it a terminal rule. Assuming that it doesn't overlap with any other rules, that shouldn't lead to any problems.

Comment: You mean changing it to "TAGINDEX
 : DOLLARDOLLAR 'TAGINDEX' ASSIGN tagid=INT DOLLARDOLLAR
 ;". I have already tried that, but if I do so then I cannot access the 'tagid' in my Listener/Visitor since TAGINDEX is the only symbol. I would then have to parse TAGINDEX().GetText() to look for the INT which I can certainly do, but I was hoping to avoid doing that. Just to have ANTLR do the parsing for me.

Comment: @XBond I'm afraid there's a way around parsing `GetText()`. It seems like ANTLR4 ignores labels in lexer rules, so there's no way to access the individual subpatterns.